# Activating DNSSEC on domain hosted at different registrar

Tags: dnssec

We are currently hosting a domain at our DNS provider but the domain is registered elsewhere.
If we create the required DNSSEC records, the registrar will need to create a DS record right?

Will this cause any downtime if the registrar has not yet entered this required DS record?

Comment: Done! Thanks you for your detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this cannot cause downtime, because the signature chain goes from `DS record at registrar` to `DNSSEC record at nameserver`. So if there's no `DS` record, there's nothing to point to the `DNSSEC` record and say "validate that".

The only way you get downtime is by having a `DS` record at your registrar but not having the proper `DNSSEC` record on your nameserver.

I am not 100% certain, but this is my understanding of how it works.

Comment: Can confirm this did not cause any downtime.